# Samba4 Workgroup showing in My computer Properties

Tags: linux, domain, samba4, kerberos

I suppose my question is stupid but want to clear it. Installed Samba4, joined machine but in My Computer properties the WORKGROUP is shown in lowercase letters. Whats is the reason to don't show in UpperCase letters. For example it shows like example.com not like EXAMPLE.COM like genuine Windows AD.
The host part is in uppercase and the domain part is in lower case. I want Workgroup to be shown in uppercase always. Tested with win xp (win xp join samba 3,5 version dc the workgroup is in uppercase, the same machine join my samba 4.1.2 and the workgroup is in lowercase).. the problem is not in windows 7.

Comment: Is that about the domain part of the full computer name displayed in computer properties, or where are you looking up the realm? We have "genuine" AD here (hosted on Windows server machines) and the AD domain shows in all lowercase letters (whereas the computer name is uppercase, but I'm not 100% this is a requirement).

Comment: I don't say its requirement just whats the reason because before I had 2k3 AD and different server with samba 3,5 where the domain was shown in uppercase. Its about the host name and also where I lookup the realm, now its shown everywhere lowercase. Just curios how can make the realm to be shown in uppercase :)

Comment: Still no answer or explanation on my quest... somebody?